# How to reindex primary key table in OLEDB with VB.NET

Tags: sql, oledb, alter-table, dbf, oledbcommand

I created my own index primary key with the .NET progran VB.NET. So how can my solution re-index the primary key and then load the database

Thanks

[image: Already index]

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("ALTER TABLE RPD ADD CONSTRAINT idxMyTable PRIMARY KEY (PNM,NOD)", cn)

                    cn.Open()
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                End Using
            End Using

            LoadData()



        End Sub
```

Comment: you will need to drop the constraint before re-adding it

Comment: @MitchWheat , Thank You Your reply, How can I do the drop first with the code I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's [a link](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_drop_index.asp)!

```
                Using cn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
                    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("DROP INDEX idxMyTable ON RPD;", cn)

                        cn.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    End Using
                End Using
```